# Unable to Convert Json Response to an Entity by ClientResponse class

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have below method addAppearance(BasicInfo basicInfo)

```
private static Boolean addAppearance(BasicInfo basicInfo){
    Boolean inserted = false;
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    String jsonObj = gson.toJson(basicInfo);

    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/Services/webapi/appearance");
        ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, jsonObj.toString());

        basicInfo = clientResponse.getEntity(BasicInfo.class);

    if(clientResponse.getStatus()==200)
     inserted = true;

    return inserted;
}
```

After hitting the url by client.resource()  I am getting a Json Response

```
    {
    "appearanceId": 24,
    "bodyType": "SLIM",
    "healthInfo": "LOW_BP",
    "height_cm": 101,
    "height_feet": 3,
    "height_inch": 8,
    "skinTone": "VERY_FAIR",
    "weight": 34
}
```

But I am not able to convert that response to BasicInfo class.

BasicInfo.java

```
public class BasicInfo {
private int appearanceId;
private int height_feet;
private int height_inch;
private int height_cm;
private int weight;
private String fullName;
private String maritalStatus;
private String bodyType;
private String healthInfo;
private String skinTone;
private String disability;
private String bloodgroup;
public String getBodyType() {
    return bodyType;
}
public void setBodyType(String bodyType) {
    this.bodyType = bodyType;
}
public int getAppearanceId() {
    return appearanceId;
}
public void setAppearanceId(int appearanceId) {
    this.appearanceId = appearanceId;
}
public int getHeight_feet() {
    return height_feet;
}
public void setHeight_feet(int height_feet) {
    this.height_feet = height_feet;
}
public int getHeight_inch() {
    return height_inch;
}
public void setHeight_inch(int height_inch) {
    this.height_inch = height_inch;
}
public int getHeight_cm() {
    return height_cm;
}
public void setHeight_cm(int height_cm) {
    this.height_cm = height_cm;
}
public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}
public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}
public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}
public String getMaritalStatus() {
    return maritalStatus;
}
public void setMaritalStatus(String maritalStatus) {
    this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
}

public String getHealthInfo() {
    return healthInfo;
}
public void setHealthInfo(String healthInfo) {
    this.healthInfo = healthInfo;
}
public String getSkinTone() {
    return skinTone;
}
public void setSkinTone(String skinTone) {
    this.skinTone = skinTone;
}
public String getDisability() {
    return disability;
}
public void setDisability(String disability) {
    this.disability = disability;
}
public String getBloodgroup() {
    return bloodgroup;
}
public void setBloodgroup(String bloodgroup) {
    this.bloodgroup = bloodgroup;
}
}
```

Comment: I have also tried .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), still it is not converting to Java object.

Comment: Stack trace? Behavior?

Comment: I got below error .  12:51:45.185 [tomcat-http--16] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class sanfotech.msk.model.BasicInfo, and Java type class sanfotech.msk.model.BasicInfo, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

Comment: if this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341788/jersey-clientresponse-getentity-of-generic-type