# JAX-RS GET: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain

Tags: jersey, javax

I'm getting following error while trying to do JAX-RS GET request:

```
MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain, type=class com.intuit.accountant.services.common.cdm.Job, genericType=class com.intuit.accountant.services.common.cdm.Job
```

Below is my code:

```
Response response = target("jobs/Hello")
        .request()
        .header("intuit_offeringid", "testOfferingId")
        .header(RequestHeaders.REALM, CommonUtil.DEFAULT_REALM_ID_FOR_INTUIT_EMPLOYEE)
        .header(RequestHeaders.AUTH, "002923")
        .header(RequestHeaders.TICKET,"00303")
        .get(Response.class);
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show server code also ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to post all the code. The error is almost assuredly not happening in that code sample you posted. The get(Response.class) is converting it to a generic http response where you can see the response payload, status, response headers etc.

What you didn't post would most likely look somemthing like this. response.readEntity(com.intuit.accountant.services.common.cdm.Job)

In this case you don't have a reader registered to convert a text/plain response from the server to an entity. I don't know if the response was supposed to be json/xml and you are receiving text because there was an error of some kind. You should check the response as text like this to see what you are getting. This will probably point you in the right direction. If you are getting text you would have to write an implementation of MessageBodyReader to convert the plain text into an entity.

Try this...

```
System.out.println("Response body is " + response.getEntity(String.class));
```

Comment: The method `getEntity(Class<T> entityType)` doesn't exist in the `Response` class, you probably meant `readEntity(Class<T> entityType)`.

Comment: If it is Jersey 2, then it is getEntity() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341788/jersey-clientresponse-getentity-of-generic-type

Comment: With Jersey 2 the line `response.readEntity(String.class)` will return the response body as a string, in Jersey 2 `.getEntity` doesn't accept any arguments and returns an `Object` that you can call .toString for (that for some reason gives a Connector object for me)