# How to get variable list JSON body in Jersey/Dropwizard?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, dropwizard

I want to get the list of variable parameters in JSON format of a POST request to a Jersey/Dropwizard backend.

Consider the json body in a POST request

```
{
 "tag1" : "tag1" ,
 "parameter" : 
    [ "key1" : "value1", 
      "key2" : "value2" ]
 }
```

Now the length of the parameters might vary so I was wondering how to access these key and values.

I tried the block

```
 @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response insertJob(
      @PathParam("tag1") String tag1,
      @PathParam("parameter") List<Result> parameters
  ) {

    return Response.ok(resultList).build();

  }
```

but I get I get the error

```
No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response ....
```

I was wondering what injection I am missing. by the way I use guice as an dependency injector

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341788/jersey-clientresponse-getentity-of-generic-type

Comment: Can you post your configuration about Jersey and jackson ?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary any special config, try to use a POJO as in my answer instead of a PathParam (a path param is in the URL path)

Answer (score 0):

Jackson will do everything for if declare a simple POJO to map your JSON, just like this:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Result> insertJob(MySimplePOJO pojo ) {

    [...]

    return resultList;
}

class MySimplePOJO  {
    public String tag1;
    public List<Result> parameters;
}
```