# Hashmap Example in Java using Jersey?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jersey

I am currently working with with web services for the first time and I have to write some examples of different web services in Jersey using Maven,

But I can only seem to get it to work in Spark (Here's My spark example)

```
//Hashmap Example
get("add/:num1/:num2", new Route() {

    @Override
    public Object handle(Request rqst, Response rspns) throws Exception {
        rspns.type("application/json");

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(rqst.params(":num1"));
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(rqst.params(":num2"));
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("result", num1+num2);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(map);
    }
});
```

I just need some help writing it for a Jersey example ?

Any help you can offer would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself

```
//HashMap Example
@GET
@Path("add/{num1}/{num2}")
public String Hashmap(@PathParam("num1") int num1, @PathParam("num2") int num2){
          HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
          map.put("result", num1+num2);
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          return gson.toJson(map);
}
```

Comment: Note that it is not because you "can" create the Json yourself that you "should".  Other than that, I don't see how your solution differs from mine.

Answer (score 0):

First, with Jersey you need to register a JSonProvider, so that you can return an Object and it will be serialized for you in JSON. You can alternatively support XML with no more effort.

Personally I use Jackson. The default with Jersey is Moxy, which doesn't support Maps, and has "issues" even with simple List (you need to wrap them) see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081546/jersey-can-produce-listt-but-cannot-response-oklistt-build)

Configuring Jersey with Jackson : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson

Moxy issue with Map : [How to return a JSON object from a HashMap with Moxy and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322605/how-to-return-a-json-object-from-a-hashmap-with-moxy-and-jersey)

Here's a working example of a Jersey web service, returning a Map, given you are using Jackson

```
@GET
@Path("add/{num1}/{num2}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getClubNames(@PathParam("num1") Integer num1, @PathParam("num2") Integer num2) {

    Map<String, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    returnMap.put("resultAsString", Integer.toString(num1 + num2));
    returnMap.put("resultAsInt", num1 + num2);

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(returnMap).build();

}
```

Personal note, as you are starting to use Jersey :

I really like Jersey. But there is a serious hard-coupling issue with HK2. https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1933. This is out of scope, but you should understand what this means before choosing a JAX-RS 2.0 implementation. In a stand alone Web Application, Jersey works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the information but this was not quiet what I was looking for, I have now figured it out and posted the answer below for anyone that needs it