# Return list as json using jersey/spring rest server giving errors?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I want to be able to add a new header to my response.
I am getting the error:

org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.

My code is as follows:

```
@GET
 @Path("/persons")
 @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
 public Response getPersons()
 {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    persons.add(new Person(1, "John Smith"));
    persons.add(new Person(2, "Jane Smith"));

 return Response.ok(persons).build();
 }
```

When I use "List" as the return type and return "persons", there is a successful return, but when I return a "Response" I get the error. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

The exception tells that you don't have `MessageBodyWriter` provider. Basically, because of `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` it means that you need some json framwork in your dependencies or custom implementation for `@Provider` More info about providers [1.1 JAX-RS](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-420004.2) (can't find JSR 339 spec online, can download pdf from [here 2.0 JAX-RS](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/))

Probably this will solve it for you:

**For gradle**

```
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22.2'
```

**For Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Choose appropriate version for yours setup from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson

Btw: [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207252/messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-application-json), [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762109/obtaining-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-application-json-trying-t), [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136404/severe-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-application-json-type-class), [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601842/jersey-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-application-json-type-class)

---

Update after `@peeskillet` comment.

Good point with that there is already some json assosiated provider, but it can't marshal Response with List for some reason. I can't say much about it, because we need to see your setup (pom or gradle build file) or you could try to use something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081716/1032167 or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35039968/1032167 to solve it.

---

So, use (option 1) `Jackson` or use (option 2)

```
GenericEntity<List<Person>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Person>>(persons) {};
Response.ok(entity).build();
```

Comment: This should work, but your reasoning is incorrect. See the OP's last statement in the question. Then have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35039294/2587435). Seems the OP already has a provider, but is probably not using Jackson, maybe MOXy. In which case, just adding Jackson would not work, they would still need to _remove_ MOXy.

Comment: @peeskillet you are absolutly right. For some strange reason i skiped the last line in OP post. Btw nice explanation in link you provided

Answer (score 0):

Register Jackson feature into your Jersey config. This will automatically adds Jackson inbound and outbound mapping features to Jersey.

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        ...
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        ...
    }
```

See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson for more information.